# No return value after moving XSLT transformation to other project

Tags: java, xml, xslt, transformation

I have the following piece of code to transform an xml document to a html page. It's nothing special, just that I use the saxon factory for transforming as I need a function from XSLT 2.0.

```
try {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    StreamResult output = new StreamResult(bos);
    StreamSource input = new StreamSource(new FileReader(TransformationTest.class.getResource(sourceFileName).getFile()));
    StreamSource stylesheet = new StreamSource(TransformationTest.class.getResourceAsStream(STYLESHEET));

    Transformer tr = TransformerFactory.newInstance("net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl", null).newTransformer(stylesheet);
    tr.transform(input, output);

    return bos.toString();
} catch (TransformerException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("XSL-Transform: Error while transforming the document.");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("XSL-Transform: Error while reading the source file.");
}
```

The code is working fine in a seperate project with saxon added as a dependency. I tried it with different inputs and everytime I got the right output.

Now I tried adding it to a bigger project which has many many other libraries in the classpath and suddenly the code stops working. The output is just blank, no exceptions, no error messages, just a blank string that will be returned. I'm not an expert of what is happening in the transformer, so I need a bit of help here. What exactly could be reason for this behaviour and how can I fix it?

Comment: Well start with running your code with Saxon 9 from the command line and check if it then also does not output anything but the empty string. If that is the case then we need to see the XSLT and the input. In many cases it is a problem with namespaces e.g. the XSLT does `<xsl:template match="foo">...</xsl:template>` while the XML input has `<foo xmlns="http://example.com/">...</foo>`.